# There was a problem: Incorrect syntax near the keywoard 'as'

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Error:**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyboard 'as'.

**Code:**

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string str_connection = "Data Source = MSSQLServer058; Initial Catalog = CarRental; Integrated Security = True";
            string MyUpd = "Update [dbo].[Booking] as t1, Car as t2, Customer as t3 " +
                           "set t1.[CustomerID] = '" + lblCustomerID.Text + "'," +
                           "t1.[VIN] = '" + lblVIN.Text + "'," +
                                "t3.[DriverLicNo] = '" + DriverLicNotxt.Text + "'" +
                           "t2.[Make] = '" + txtMake.Text + "'" +

            MessageBox.Show("Save Complete!", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation on what you are doing, what is going wrong and what is the expected result.

Comment: You ***need*** to parametrise your queries! What you have there is a huge security hole and you need to fill it in ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to update multiple tables in one go - this is not possible.

Change your SQL to do multiple updates, if you need to, encapsulate in a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE [dbo].[Booking] set ...
UPDATE Car ...
UPDATE Customer ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 1):

I always make this caveat when providing a C# answer: I am *not* a C# developer. I really have very little experience with it. What I did is what I always do when showing someone how to parametrise a query, I check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8):

```cs
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str_connection = "Data Source = MSSQLServer058; Initial Catalog = CarRental; Integrated Security = True";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str_connection))
    {

        //Do your queries really have no WHERE?
        string MyUpd = "UPDATE dbo.Booking SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, VIN = @VIN; " +
                        "UPDATE dbo.Car SET Make = @Make; " + 
                        "UPDATE dbo.Customer SET DriverLicNo = @LicNo;";

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(MyUpd,conn))
        {

            comm.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblCustomerID.Text; //Guessed data type
            comm.Parameters.Add("@VIN",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = lblVIN.Text; //Guessed data type
            comm.Parameters.Add("@Make",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = txtMake.Text; //Guessed data type
            comm.Parameters.Add("@DriverLicNo",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = DriverLicNotxt.Text; //Guessed data type

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Save Complete!", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch
            {
                /* Your Error handling */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For those who definitely have more experience with C#, if anything is wrong please do leave a comment and I'll be happy to fix (or submit an edit). Hopefully, at least, this gets the OP on the right track though.

Comment: you should use using for SqlCommand as well as SqlConnection so it gets disposed. Also, you're missing a line. `comm.CommandText = MyUpd;`

Comment: Something like that, @AndyNichols?

Comment: Yes, also I edited my comment that the command text isn't being set. I've also just noticed `new SqlCommand(comm,conn)` must be wrong as comm is the variable you're setting up.

Comment: Yeah, just changed it to `SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(MyUpd,conn)`. Is that right, @AndyNichols?